# Changing Domain Name Without Problem of Copied Content

Tags: seo, google, copy

I need to change the one site domain name. It is something very similar to EMD. Because of EMD is bad now a days, I am try to move it to brand name and I hope that it will give extra traffic too.

**I know that I need to use 301 redirection and I will do it.**

But I have a different problem.

There are two many websites which copied my articles on the internet already.

Because of my domain name (new domain) is new, will Google consider my domain has copied content because of those sites?

Answer (score -1):

Map your URLs

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033086?hl=en&ref_topic=6033084

Use 301s to redirect to your new pages. Go to Google's Search Console and there's a place to let them know you're changing your address. I think that's about all you can do to safeguard yourself. Good luck!